# Django rest framework manage.py ImportError

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I've created a project 'mysite' and added the necessary statements in their respective files according to http://johnnyprogrammer.blogspot.com/2013/08/creating-rest-service-with-django-and.html

When I run the command:

```
    python manage.py runserver
```

I get the following error message :

ImportError: No module named mysiterest_frameworkdjango.contrib

How do I resolve this error?

Comment: You probably made a typo soemwhere.. Read the stacktrace. If you can't figure it out, post the stacktrace and the relevant code.

Comment: Looks like a skipped comma at settings.py.

Answer (score 2):

It is just a guess, but you may have omitted a comma or two at `settings.py`:

```
 INSTALLED_APPS = (
     ...
     'mysite'
     'rest_framework'
     'django.contrib',
 )
```

It should be:

```
 INSTALLED_APPS = (
     ...
     'mysite',
     'rest_framework',
     'django.contrib',
 )
```

Since Python concatenates a sequence of string literals separated only by white space (including newlines if inside parenthesis), it would fit the error message you got.

```
>>> a = "foo" "bar"
>>> a
'foobar'
>>> a = (
...: "foo"
...: "baz"
...: "bar"
...: )
>>> a
'foobazbar'
```